# Can Java webstart dialog caption be overridden?

Tags: java, javafx, java-web-start

I have an Angular web application as well as a client JavaFX program that I host on an IIS 7 web server. When user clicks on a link on a page in the web app, I construct the proper JNLP file and send it down to the browser. The client browser then opens the JNLP file and the app loads and then opens properly. No issues.

But the webstart dialog that appears after clicking on the link shows a progress bar as it downloads the java application from the server, and it's got a caption that says 'JavaFX Application Preview'. I'd much rather have it say the name of the software the user is downloading. Is this possible? If so, where should I start looking?

I hunted online and couldn't find a single mention of this, which I find really surprising. Surely this has come up before?

Comment: What is the content of the `title` element in the JNLP?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Andrew.. the title is already set within the JNLP, but does nothing for the download box. I also added an icon (kind=splash), which gives a nice splash screen while starting the app from cache, but my issue is for when the app is initially downloaded into the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom Preloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABHADJH) and in the [start](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start%28javafx.stage.Stage%29) method of the preloader, [set the title](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29) of the preloader stage.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea! This is exactly what I was missing. Much appreciated!